# Is this allowed? Content update on iOS through XML-RPC

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, store

Goodmorning,

I was wondering if it is allowed to update content in an iOS app, through XML-RPC.

It's an information app. Has a top and bottom bar containing primary navigational items or topics, tapping on an icon in one of those bars will present a list with sub topicsin the center. Tapping on one of those will bring up the information itself.

This information as well as topics update a lot. I know apps can get information through feed mechanisms, that is why apps for like twitter, news etc work ...however I was wondering if it's allowed to update the primary and secondary topics (and of course the information itself) through for example XML-RPC.

Or is there some nuance difference in the way the app-store guidelines allow for Twitter client type's of apps, and information types of apps?

Hope someone can shed some light on this
Thanks
Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Definitely allowed.

Some people have run afoul of the app store gestapo when they made prototyping apps, where you could load an entire user interface from xml and simulate it on screen. That is a very extreme case. If it's just dynamic content, knock yourself out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that. I've actually recently released an app that updates the whole content from a remote xml file when the user searches for updates. Another example would be the Financial Times app, that probably does something similar as well.